# Discord Python Bot: Clear Command If statements

Tags: python, discord

I am currently tying to make a discord bot in python. It has been about 1 week since I started learning and I thought I would give this a go. I am trying to make a clear function to have it clear the chat. I want to make the bot say "please enter a valid number". If you type anything else other than an `int` ex. some char.

For example when I put ".clear t" it wont do anything and it gets angry in the terminal. When I put a valid argument such as ".clear 3" it will throw up the "please enter a valid number." after clearing all of it.

I tried different variations of the if statement including placement. Can't figure it out. I have a feeling it be something about where to place the if statement. Thank you for taking the time to read.

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def clear(ctx, number = 5):
     number = int(number) 
     counter = 0
     channel = ctx.message.channel
     async for x in client.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number):
         if counter < number:
             await client.delete_message(x)
             counter += 1
             await asyncio.sleep(0.5) 
     if number != int():
             await client.send_message(channel, "Please enter a valid number.")
```

Comment: `if number != int():` what is this supposed to do?  `int()` with no arguments always returns 0.  Did you mean to pass some argument to `int()`?

Comment: No I didn't mean to add arguments. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to properly check an object's type. In your case, if `number = 5`, and you do `if number != int():`, since `int()` returns `0`, you're basically saying `if 5 != 0:`, which is always.

To overcome the aforementioned, use`isinstance(obj, type)`. However, it doesn't matter since `number` will always be a string (unless the default value is used).

---

Having the following line will raise an error if `number` cannot be converted into an integer.

```
number = int(number)
```

Which raises a `ValueError`, you need to catch that in order to send your error message.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def clear(ctx, number=5):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    try:
        number = int(number) 
    except ValueError:
        return await client.send_message(channel, "Please enter a valid number.")

    async for x in client.logs_from(channel, limit=number):
        await client.delete_message(x)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```

With discord.py however, there's an easier way to do type conversations, by using the type annotation syntax:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def clear(ctx, number: int=5):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    async for x in client.logs_from(channel, limit=number):     
        await client.delete_message(x)            
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```

If you desperately need to send that error message to the channel, you can do it from the `on_command_error` event. (Search their documentation)

---

You might've noticed that I removed the `counter` part, since `limit` does exactly the same thing. (Removed redundancy)